# Sourcing from multiple workspaces

Tags: ros, catkin, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am just running through the ROS tutorials for Indigo (running on Ubuntu 14.04). In my .bashrc file, I have added the line `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, to source the setup file. If I then run `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, it gives me `/home/karnivaurus/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks`.

However, I also have downloaded another package, located in `~/ROS/src`. I now want to source the setup file for this new package, so that ROS knows to search there if I reference this package. Therefore, I add another line to .bashrc, `source ~/ROS/devel/setup.bash`.

The problem is that if I now run `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` again, it gives me `/home/karnivaurus/ROS/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks`. So, it seems that the second of the two lines in .bashrc overrides the first, and the package created in the tutorial can no longer be found by ROS.

So the only solution I have come up with is to have all my packages in the same workspace. But this means that I cannot run the tutorial whilst also playing around with some other packages I've downloaded. Is it normal to just have one workspace which contains all packages you have built / downloaded (i.e. other than the ones that come with ROS by default)? Or is there another solution to this?

I have inspected the setup.bash files for both these workspace, and they are identical:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# generated from catkin/cmake/templates/setup.bash.in

CATKIN_SHELL=bash

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR=$(builtin cd "`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_CATKIN_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205976/sourcing-from-multiple-workspaces/) by [Karnivaurus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21659/karnivaurus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-03-26**:
@jarvisschultz's answer is correct, but you can also pass the `--extend` argument to the setup.bash file and it will only add to the environment rather than set the environment. This can be dangerous though, and I highly recommend you do proper workspace chaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you first run `catkin_make` in the root of a workspace, the `devel` directory gets created and the `setup.bash` file inside of that dir is designed to "overlay" the workspace on top of all other workspaces that have already been sourced. It is quite common to have many "active" workspaces at a single time. In your case, I'd do the following:

1. In a new terminal run `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`
2. cd into `~/ROS/` and run `rm -r devel/` to remove the devel directory
3. run `catkin_make` from the `~/ROS/` directory (this will re-create devel/)
4. Then `source ~/ROS/devel/setup.bash`

Your environment should now have the `~/ROS/` workspace overlayed on the `~/catkin_ws/` workspace. Read more here: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raarenst](https://answers.ros.org/users/21543/raarenst/) on 2015-10-19**:
I also need to remove the build folder. Under step 2: rm -r build

**Comment by [Behsad Ghanei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26974/behsad-ghanei/) on 2016-05-25**:
But isn't that dangerous?  For example if two different workspaces have similar packages. How does ROS know from which workspace  it should run a launchfile?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-05-25**:
You need to be careful to `source devel/setup.bash` for the correct workspace.

**Comment by [Alex_Nitsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28811/alex_nitsch/) on 2017-02-21**:
Will  this work if I have one workspace that I built with catkin_make and the other one (the ~/ROS/ one) with catkin build?

**Comment by [Danfoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32545/danfoa/) on 2019-01-08**:
It seems not to, I did it with a source installation of moveit, and it does not work.

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-10-01**:
I attempted to use this method with "build" and "make" to no avail. When I did both with "build" it worked like a charm.